QT calls getOpenFileName but the operating system error occurs?
Currently I use Qt. I call QFileDialog::getOpenFileName, but I can't get the path of the file. After I try to change the code to GB2312 buf, I still can't get Chinese Path; And every call the function the out window show a lot of Garbled.
Here is the code and picture:
#include<QFileDialog>
#include<QTextCodec>

void MainDialog::slot_uploadFile(bool flag)
{
    qDebug()<<__func__;
    //弹出窗口 选择文件
    QString path=QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,"选择文件","./");
    QTextCodec *code=QTextCodec::codecForName("GB2312");
    std::string pathName=code->fromUnicode(path).data();
    if(path.isEmpty()) return ;
    //发送信号
    QString dir=ui->lb_path->text();
    //发送信号 核心类处理 传递的信息：上传到什么文件到 什么目录下
    qDebug()<<dir;
    Q_EMIT SIG_uploadfile(QString::fromStdString(pathName),dir);
}


I can't understand the output of the system. I want to know what I can do using Qt. Or, is there another function I can use?
Here is GPT's answer for the garbage output,what can I do ?
This text contains some error messages and code paths.

onecoreuap\internal\shell\inc\private\SharedStorageSources\dvthumbnail.cpp(2295)\SHELL32.dll!7541A940: This seems to point to a specific location within the codebase related to shell functionality.

(caller: 7541A64A) ReturnHr(1) tid(51b4) 80070057: This part of the message might indicate a call error, possibly due to a function call or method returning an incorrect HRESULT value 80070057, which typically represents a parameter error or an inappropriate call.

����������: These garbled characters may be due to encoding or parsing issues related to the error mentioned above.

mincore\com\oleaut32\dispatch\ups.cpp(2126)\OLEAUT32.dll!765B2D27: This part seems to point to components related to COM (Component Object Model), where there may be some dispatch or distribution errors.

(caller: 765B54BF) ReturnHr(1) tid(51b4) 8002801D: This part may represent another HRESULT error, 8002801D is typically related to registry operations.

��û��ע�ᡣ: These characters are also garbled, likely due to character encoding or parsing errors.

onecore\vm\dv\storage\plan9\rdr\dll\util.cpp(99)\p9np.dll!622BEBC3: This part seems to point to a specific location within the codebase related to storage components.

(caller: 622B81B9) LogHr(1) tid(34cc) C0000034: This may represent another error, C0000034 is typically related to system or driver errors.

Msg:[�����V���꾴?���Pɢ?�L?�u����??����������?��î�b��?���N�ᠹ????߾?��?Ҳ�y?????߲??��?????߲??��??��??��?�珔??????��ƫ��???߲��?�ֵ͵�?����??߼?���H��??]: This is an error message, but due to garbled characters, the specific message content cannot be determined.


Overall, these error messages indicate that you've encountered some issues related to the system, components, or drivers, possibly involving parameter errors, character encoding problems, or system/component call errors. Resolving these issues may require further debugging and troubleshooting.

In your example, there's no need to convert it to GB2312 - just use QString directly. The garbage output in terminal may be another issue.

"选择文件" is a char[] string whose interpretation depends on your compiler's codepage settings. You should use QString::fromStdWString(L"选择文件") instead.

this is error in string conversion - ansi to unicode in p9np.dll. ansi msg is printed as unicode. real Msg is "NtCreateFile(&device, SYNCHRONIZE, &attributes, &ioStatus, nullptr, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, (FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE), FILE_OPEN, FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT, nullptr, 0)"
